# ¿Tkinter dejó de funcionar en Osx?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, macos

Estoy tratando de integrar GUI a mis programas en python utilizo Osx High Sierra, a lo que eh investigado hay una libreria "Tkinter" para realizar apps con GUI por más que eh buscado tutoriales, guías, etc... no encuentro nada actualizado casi todo es del año 2016. ¿A caso se volvió obsoleto? ó ¿hay mejores herramientas para este tipo de proyectos en Osx? (los únicos tutoriales "nuevos" son en windows 10 y en Linux.

Comment: Tkinter es una librería muuy antigua (ya venía con el primer python) y no se ha actualizado, por lo que los tutorials del 2006 deberían seguir siendo válidos. Hay cosas más modernas, como PyQt, pero el inconveniente es que tienes que instalarlos, mientars que tkinter viene preinstalado por ser parte de python.

Comment: Si, justo estaba viendo las otra opciones, además de que por lo que vi también es posible el utilizar Xcode, gracias por tu respuesta.